# Paint job gone wrong

Tags: paint

In the past I bumped my car against a garage shelf and fixed a deep scratch by removing the clear coat of the area, sanding, masking, priming and then coats of paint and clear coat. It worked great.

Some time after another accident happened, this time with a dent. So I did the same thing, but 2 things were different: I used a body filler and I didn't have time (had to commute the next morning) to leave the primer to say on for 24 hours before painting as the instruction advised.

When I did it, about 3 weeks ago, the job has some primer left out on the side, which I intended to clean with some T-cut (hopefully), but apart from that all else was OK.

But after 2 washes and some time in the sun and 3 weeks later the photo shows the start difference, it looks awful, but in the first few days it looked almost completely blended. I think it must be due to the primer?

It really looked nothing like this initially:
[image: 3 weeks later]

Please advise on fixing this, should I:

1. Remove the new clear coat
2. Sand? (how much and girths?)
3. Prime, do it right this time
4. Paint coats
5. Clear coat

It seems like some body filler transpires underneath, some of the dent is still not smooth, I am really worried I won't be able to fix it. Any tips for cleaning the primer I accidentally have sprayed over the old clear coat next to the side signal light? I don't understand what caused this to look so awful, in the first days it looked completely blended apart from the over-spray.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!